# Bootstrap reset input but not all variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
              <div class="tab-pane" >

              <label> user:</label>
              <input type="text" class="span3" name="user" id="user"  /><br/>
             <label> Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="span3" name="pass" id="pass" /><br/>
             <br/>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="login()">Register</button>
         <button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">reset</button><br/>

                   </div>
```

it is my html code.I want to reset all variable but i don't use form.

Comment: Attach click event handler to reset button and reset each value of input elements manually in event handler function.

Comment: Write a javascript function that will empty the form for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="test_input" id="test_input" value=""/>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-success" id="reset_btn" name="reset_btn">Reset</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document").ready(function(){

   $("#reset_btn").click(function() {
      $("#test_input").val('');
   });

});
```

This is a really basic example as it's only reseting one input box. You can just use jQuery selectors to reset all form elements on the page.

To reset every element with an `<input>` tag you can use:

```
$("input").val('');
```

Here is a JSFiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/WPg2T/2/

Further information on the jQuery click handler can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

try with using jquery, lyk below, i think it will help for u

```
<script>
$( "#resetbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "input" ).val("");
});
</script>
```

add id #resetbutton for reset button

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).load(function()
{
   $([type=reset]).trigger('click');
})
```